# Spring Batch Remote Chunking Chunk Response

Tags: spring, spring-batch, chunking

I have implemented Spring Batch Remote Chunking with Kafka. I have implemented both Manager and worker configuration. I want to send some DTO or object in chunkresponse from worker side to Manager and do some processing once I receive the response. Is there any way to achieve this.  I want to know the count of records processed after each chunk is processed from worker side and I have to update the database frequently with count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to send some DTO or object in chunkresponse from worker side to Manager and do some processing once I receive the response.  Is there any way to achieve this.

I'm not sure the remote chunking feature was designed to send items from the manager to workers and back again. The [ChunkResponse](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/integration/chunk/ChunkResponse.html) is what the manager is expecting from workers and I see no way you can send processed items in it (except probably serializing the item in the `ChunkResponse#message` field, or storing it in the execution context, which both are not good ideas..).

> I want to know the count of records processed after each chunk is processed from worker side and I have to update the database frequently with count.

The `StepContribution` is what you are looking for here. It holds all the counts (read count, write count, etc). You can get the step contribution from the `ChunkResponse` on the manager side and do what is required with the result.

Comment: @Mahmound Ben Hassine Thanks alot for your answer I am using kafka as messaging platform with Remote Chunking and with StepContribution I am able to get the count of write and process and also skip record count. I need to speed application specific Id so I set it in the StepExecutionContextMap and use Kafka Interceptor to read it on manager side before Channel ItemWriter.